# Swift: math operation on regex capture numbers

Tags: regex, swift, capture

I like to change "I run 12 miles" to "I run 24 miles" using regex. "12" can be any number. I use the function "replace2()" to do the math operation. The capture parameter "$1" in passed to function replace2("$1") is fine. Please help!

```
func replace( str:String, pattern : String, repl:String)->String?{
    let regex = NSRegularExpression .regularExpressionWithPattern(pattern, options: nil,error: nil)
    let replacedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString( str, options: nil,
        range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements( str)), withTemplate: repl )
    return replacedString

}
replace( "I run 12 miles and walk 12.45 km","\\d+(.\\d+)?", "-")!

func replace2(x: String)->String {
    let xx = x.toInt()! * 2     // error : return nil?
    return String(format: "\(xx)")
}
replace( "I run 12 miles ","(\\d+)", replace2("$1") )!    // error
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a playground:

```
let str1: NSString = "I run 12 miles"
let str2 = "I run 12 miles"

let match = str1.rangeOfString("\\d+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
let finalStr = str1.substringWithRange(match).toInt()
let n: Double = 2.2*Double(finalStr!)

let newStr = str2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\d+", withString: "\(n)", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)

println(newStr) //I run 26.4 miles


//or more simply
let newStr2 = "I run \(n) kilometers"
//yes, I know my conversion is off
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I try to multiply many (unkown) numbers like

Comment: "I run 34 miles and 10.54 km in -34F degrees." I like multiply all the 3 numbers by 2.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But I try to use pure Swift and try to get away from "NS" stuff as much as possible, besides being redundant. Can you double all numbers in string "I run 34 miles and 10.54 km in -34F degrees" to "I run 68 miles and 21.08 km in -68F degrees". In Perl it's simple: "s/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/$1 * 2/ge"

Comment: If you want I can do a swift function.  Longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically catch the values and replace them based upon the captured value, you have to use `enumerateMatchesInString`. You can then then write a loop that does the replacements:

```
func stringWithDoubleNumbers(string: String) -> String {
    // build array of ranges that need replacing

    var ranges = [NSRange]()
    let regex  = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[\\d.]+", options: nil, error: nil) as NSRegularExpression
    regex.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(string))) {
        match, flags, stop in

        ranges.append(match.range)
    }

    var doubledString = NSMutableString(string: string)

    // iterate backwards so that location is valid despite other replacements

    for range in reverse(ranges) {
        let foundString = doubledString.substringWithRange(range)

        if let value = foundString.toInt() {
            let numericString = "\(value * 2)"
            doubledString.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: numericString)
        } else {
            let value = NSString(string: foundString).doubleValue
            let numericString = "\(value * 2.0)"
            doubledString.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withString: numericString)
        }
    }

    return doubledString
}
```

I do some additional logic to handle integer values differently than floating point types, but you could simplify this if you don't want to worry about that complication.

Answer (score 0):

// I experiment with Steve and Rob codes above, I think I can get the codes to solve the problem for simple string. I still get problem with complex string. I try to parse a data record with various multiple (-20) numbers with either integers/doubles not in any sequence like handling both str2 and str3 in a single routine. Anyway thanks to Steve and Rob.

```
let str2 = "I run 89 miles and 28.576 km"
let str3 = "I run 89.45 miles and 34 km in 34F degree"

var re = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\d+).* (\\d+\\.\\d+)", options: nil, error: nil)
var match = re.firstMatchInString(str2, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(str2)))

var startIndex = advance(str2.startIndex, match.rangeAtIndex(1).location)
var endIndex   = advance(str2.startIndex, match.rangeAtIndex(1).location + match.rangeAtIndex(1).length)
let x1 = str2.substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex, end: endIndex)).toInt()!
```

x1

```
startIndex = advance(str2.startIndex, match.rangeAtIndex(2).location)
endIndex   = advance(str2.startIndex, match.rangeAtIndex(2).location + match.rangeAtIndex(2).length)
let x2 = str2.substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex, end: endIndex))
let x2x = NSString(string: x2).doubleValue
let n1 = x1 * 2
let n2: Double = 2.0 * x2x

str2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(\\d+)(.* )(\\d+\\.\\d+)", withString: "\(n1)$2\(n2)", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
```

// I run 178 miles and 57.152 km"